# python regex: match a char surrounded by exactly 2 chars

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I need a regex in python that matches any char that is surrounded by exactly 2 underscores.
meaning, meaning

```
__a__
```

will match "a", 
but

```
___a___
```

will not match.
it needs to support overlapping matches, 
such that

```
__a__d___b___e__c__
```

will return "ac"
because a is surrounded by double underlines, but d,e have a triple one next to them and b has a triple underline on both sides.
what I have now

```
(?<=[_]{2})(.)(?=[_]{2})
```

it solves the overlapping, but not the "exactly 2"
in the above example it returns "adbec"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

```
(?<=(?<!_)__)([^_])(?=__(?!_))
```

Examples:

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r'(?<=(?<!_)__)([^_])(?=__(?!_))')
>>> regex.findall('__a__ ')
['a']
>>> regex.findall('___a___')
[]
>>> regex.findall('__a__d___b___e__c__')
['a', 'c']
>>> regex.findall('__a__c__')
['a', 'c']
```

You said you wanted overlapping matches, but if you would not like the `c` to match in `__a__c__`, use the following (which was my original answer):

```
(?<!_)__([^_])__(?!_)
```