# Replace all occurances of a character unless surrounded by two different patterns

Tags: regex, perl

I want to find a regex (preferably in perl, but any flavour will do) to replace every `_` except those preceded by exactly 8 digits **and** followed by exactly 6 digits.
Actually, I want to replace `_` in filenames except those in dates with format `YYYYMMDD_hhmmss`.
Generally speaking, I want to replace every occurrances of some character that is *not preceded by some pattern* **and** *not followed by an other pattern*.
I tried many regexes and look for at lot on the web, but I did not find anything!

I know it is possible to replace every `_` by `.`, then restore the `_` in `YYYYMMDD.hhmmss`, but I am interested in doing it in one step (hoping it is possible).

Here are some examples of replacements:

```
Patate_17890505_TitreEnCamelCase.ext  -->  Patate.17890505.TitreEnCamelCase.ext
EPFL_AlgebreLineaire                  -->  EPFL.AlgebreLineaire
ipe.20210302_005606.pdf               -->  ipe.20210302_005606.pdf
1_                                    -->  1.
12_                                   -->  12.
_1                                    -->  .1
_12                                   -->  .12
12345678_                             -->  12345678.
_123456                               -->  .123456
12345678_12345                        -->  12345678.12345
1234567_123456                        -->  1234567.123456
1234567_12345                         -->  1234567.12345
123456_12345                          -->  123456.12345
12345678_1234567                      -->  12345678.1234567
123456789_123456                      -->  123456789.123456
123456789_1234567                     -->  123456789.1234567
_patate__truc__                       -->  .patate..truc..
___                                   -->  ...
foo_12345678                          -->  foo.12345678
foo_12345678_123456_bar               -->  foo.12345678_123456.bar
12345678_123456                       -->  12345678_123456
foo12345678_123456bar                 -->  foo12345678_123456bar
```

Below, a few examples I tried.

---

Make exactly the opposite of what I want, *i.e.* replace every `_` preceded by exactly 8 digits and followed by exactly 6 digits (try it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Fi8f6g/1)):

```perl
s/((?<!\d)(?:\d{8}))_((?:\d{6})(?!\d))/$1.$2/g
```

It works, so I need the negation of this regex…

---

Just a negative lookbehind and a negative lookahead (try it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/UQN6NN/1)):

```perl
s/(?<!\d{8})_(?!\d{6})/./g
```

Fails: does not replace if `_` is preceded by exactly 8 digits **or** followed by exactly 6 digits, *e.g.* the `_` is not replaced in theses strings:

```
12345678_
_123456
12345678_12345
1234567_123456
```

I need to replace all except when “and”, but this one replaces all except when “or” (so it misses some `_`).

---

Inspired from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10821698/9249152) (from [python regex: match a char surrounded by exactly 2 chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10821585)) (try it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/E4XI74/1)):

```perl
s/(?<!(?<!\d)\d{8})_(?!\d{6}(?!\d))/./g
```

Fails: same reason as the previous one.
The regex in the original answer works because it replace chars *preceded by a pre-pattern* **and** *followed by a post-pattern*.

---

Inspired from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11459626/9249152) (from [Replace character UNLESS surrounded by specific tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11458804)), but I do not really understand how it works (try it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Ww7KxC/1)):

```perl
s/_(?:(?!(?:.*?\d{6}))|(?=[^\d]+\d{8}))/./g
```

Fails: in these examples, the `_` is not replaced

```
_123456
1234567_123456
12345678_1234567
123456789_123456
123456789_1234567
foo_12345678
```

The original problem is quite close of mine, but instead of `\d{8}` and `\d{6}`, the pre-pattern and post-pattern are HTML tags, so the problem is easier : `<tag>` and `</tag>` are unique elements where for my problem, the post-pattern `\d{6}` could be followed by an other digit (likewise the pre-pattern `\d{8}` could be preceded by an other digit).
But this one almost work, unlike the previous try, it replace the `_` in both theses string:

```
12345678_
12345678_12345
```

so perhaps a modification could make it works as I want…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<!\d)\d{8}_\d{6}(?!\d)(*SKIP)(*F)|_
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/amVZSL/1). *Details*:

- `(?<!\d)\d{8}_\d{6}(?!\d)` - eight digits, `_` and six digits not enclosed with any other digits
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - fail the match at the current location and continue the regex search from the failure location
- `|`  - or
- `_` - an underscore in any other context.

An alternative regex is

```
_(?!(?<=(?<!\d)\d{8}_)\d{6}(?!\d))
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/amVZSL/2). *Details*:

- `_` - an underscore
- `(?!(?<=(?<!\d)\d{8}_)\d{6}(?!\d))` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if  - immediately to the right of the current location - there are six (and no more than six) digits immediately preceded with exactly eight digits and an underscore.

Comment: Woah :-) ! I did not even knew about `(*SKIP)` et `(*FAIL)`. The latter one is very conter-intuitive with the `_` at the beginning, I will have to think about it!

Comment: This is almost there, but it doesn't know what a valid date is and potentially accepts more than ASCII digits (but `/a` can solve that).